# Create a new variable based on modal number of observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new variable that is based on the model number of observations of a separate variable.

Using this df:

```
help <- data.frame(
id = c(rep(05, times = 8), rep(10, times = 8), rep(12, times = 8)),
episode = c(rep(1, times = 4), rep(2, times =4), rep(3, times = 8), rep(1, times = 4), rep(2, times =4)),
provider = c(rep(70, times = 2), rep(80, times = 2), rep(70, times = 4), rep(30, times = 6), rep(40, times = 2), rep(70, times = 4), rep(10, times = 4)))
```

I am hoping to create a new variable, provider_mode that is based on the modal provider, or provider with the most observations, per episode.

The end df would look like this:

```
id episode provider provider_mode
5       1       70       70
5       1       70       70
5       1       80       70
5       1       80       70
5       2       70       70 
5       2       70       70
5       2       70       70
5       2       70       70
10      3       30       30
10      3       30       30
10      3       30       30
10      3       30       30
10      3       30       30
10      3       30       30
10      3       40       30
10      3       40       30
12      1       70       70
12      1       70       70
12      1       70       70
12      1       70       70
12      2       10       10
12      2       10       10
12      2       10       10
12      2       10       10
```

Here is the code I came up with thus far, but it only gives me the count for each provider within each episode. I need to create a mutate command that puts the provider with the most observations, and if there is a tie, select the first provider (e.g., provider 70 within id 5).

```
help %>% group_by(id, episode, provider) %>% mutate(provider_count = n())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can group by `id` and `episode` and using `table` we find the frequency of each `provider` and select the maximum of it with `which.max`.

```
library(dplyr)
help %>%
  group_by(id, episode) %>%
  mutate(provider_mode = names(which.max(table(provider))))

#     id  episode provider provider_mode
#   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>         <chr>
#1      5       1       70            70
#2      5       1       70            70
#3      5       1       80            70
#4      5       1       80            70
#5      5       2       70            70
#6      5       2       70            70
#7      5       2       70            70
#8      5       2       70            70
#9     10       3       30            30
#10    10       3       30            30
# ... with 14 more rows
```

And the similar could be achieved with `ave` from base R

```
help$provider_mode <- ave(help$provider, help$id, help$episode, FUN = function(x) 
                                      names(which.max(table(x))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is R doesn't really have a `mode()` function that calculates the statistical mode. We can fake it with `dplyr()` by calculating the counts and then merging them back in. For example if your data is stored in a variable named `dd`,

```
dd %>% 
    group_by(id, episode) %>% 
    count(provider) %>% 
    top_n(1, n) %>% 
    filter(row_number()==1) %>%
    select(-n) %>% 
    rename(provider_mode=provider) %>% 
    right_join(dd)
```

Comment: I didn't realize `top_n` would return multiple rows in case of ties. I've added an additional filter to return just one value per id.

Comment: this works as long as I due `group_by(id, episode)` ... if I don't' group by episode as well, the provider for id 12 stays the same across both episodes. thanks, flick.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `Mode` function as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
```

}

and then with `data.table`, grouped by 'id', 'episode', we get the 'Mode' of 'provider'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(help)[, provider_mode := Mode(provider), by = .(id, episode)]
```